# ¿Cómo consigo leer y guardar datos del formulario Windows?

Tags: c#, json

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Llevo un tiempo en leer y escribir datos en json, ahora estoy con la librería el Newtonjson en .NET 7.0. Digo ahora porque empecé con él a ver si me sale lo de leer y escribir datos en json.

No sabía que en la .net 7.0 ya tiene MicroSoft su propia librería que puedes [ver aquí](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.text.json?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DES-ES%26k%3Dk(System.Text.Json)%3Bk(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=net-7.0) pero ya es otro tema para probar otro día haber que tal.

Ahora me toca encontrar el error que no logro leer y guardar datos sobre los controles como checkBox, texbox y demás para guardar mi configuración del formulario Windows con .NET 7.0 en este caso.

System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Código C#:

```html
using System.IO;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace Guardar_y_cargar_datos_en_archivo.json_.NET_7._0
{

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        class MiInfo
        {
            public string? TextBox { get; set; }
            public bool CheckBox { get; set; }
            public bool RadioButton1_Luz_ON { get; set; }
            public bool RadioButton2_Luz_OFF { get; set; }
        }

        void SalvarDatos()
        {
            MiInfo miInfo = new()
            {
                TextBox = this.textBox1.Text,
                CheckBox = this.checkBox1.Checked,
                RadioButton1_Luz_ON = this.radioButton1.Checked,
                RadioButton2_Luz_OFF = this.radioButton2.Checked
            };

            try
            {
                string serializado = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(miInfo);
                File.WriteAllText(@"Ejemplo.json", serializado);
            }
            catch {}
        }

        void RecuperarDatos()
        {
            string serializado = File.ReadAllText(@"Ejemplo.json");
            MiInfo miInfo = (MiInfo)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(serializado);

            this.textBox1.Text = miInfo.TextBox;
            this.checkBox1.Checked = miInfo.CheckBox;
            this.radioButton1.Checked = miInfo.RadioButton1_Luz_ON;
            this.radioButton2.Checked = miInfo.RadioButton2_Luz_OFF;
        }

        private void button_Guardar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SalvarDatos();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            RecuperarDatos();
        }
    }
}
```

No sabía que crear un json y leer fueran tan complicado, ejjejejeje.

A ver si con el tiempo lo sacamos.

Gracias. ;)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Estimado, se me olvido responder su comentario en la otra pregunta. Yo revise el código y a mí no me da ese error.  Ese error te está indicando que `miInfo` es nulo, y lo único que se me ocurre es que el json no se haya creado, has verificado que exista el archivo?

Comment: void RecuperarDatos()
{
    if (File.Exists(@"Ejemplo.json"))
    {
        string serializado = File.ReadAllText(@"Ejemplo.json");
        MiInfo miInfo = (MiInfo)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(serializado);
        if (miInfo != null)
        {
            this.textBox1.Text = miInfo.TextBox;
            this.checkBox1.Checked = miInfo.CheckBox;
            this.radioButton1.Checked = miInfo.RadioButton1_Luz_ON;
            this.radioButton2.Checked = miInfo.RadioButton2_Luz_OFF;
        }
    }
}

Captura. https://i.postimg.cc/ZR7Xq6Bf/Captura3.jpg

Comment: Me ejecuta el programa, me guarda el archivo ejemplo.json al pulsar el botón Guardar, si cierro el programa y vuelvo a cargar, Me da el error que muestro otra vez aquí.
https://i.postimg.cc/ZR7Xq6Bf/Captura3.jpg

Comment: Captura casi completa del código.
https://i.postimg.cc/8cgXcwkm/Captura3.jpg

Comment: El error visible es NullReferenceException y esa pregunta ya existe. La otra posibilidad es que la pregunta sea cerrada porque no se puede reproducir. Por favor **pon el código como texto**. Por cierto, se me ocurre que quizá no esté encontrando el archivo y por eso es null.

Comment: Gracias. ¿Cómo qué no encuentra el archivo si lo ha creado al pulsar guardar?

Comment: Ya se lo que es y por fin funciona. Sustituí esta línea. MiInfo miInfo = (MiInfo)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(serializado); por esta otra línea, MiInfo miInfo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MiInfo>(serializado); Aún así me da un aviso a pesar de que funciona como este, https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/nullable-warnings?f1url=%3FappId%3Droslyn%26k%3Dk(CS8600) Muchísimas gracias a todos.